# Can I include my contribution to a internationally recognized research project in my college apps, if I wasn't part of the presenting team

Tags: application, cv, university, awards

I am from a non-US high school, facing a dilemma about mentioning my involvement in a successful research project (Project A) on my college applications. I contributed significantly to Project A, which has been selected to represent our nation in international science fairs like ISEF and Regeneron Talent Search. However, due to a rule at our national science fair that limited students to submitting only one project, I submitted a different project (Project B) and thus am not officially recognized for Project A. Our inquiries to include me in the official presentation team for Project A were denied. Given this situation, can I mention my Project A's accolades in my college applications? If so, how should I go about it and how would it be looked upon?

Comment: Sorry, questions about undergraduate applications are outside the scope of this site. https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300

Comment: Have a teacher mention it in a letter of recommendation.

Comment: You absolutely should mention your involvement in the project and how exactly you contributed to it. However, as Buffy says, this needs to have some corroborration beyond just your say so, ideally in the form of one or more letters of recommendation mentioning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly say specifically what you contributed to that project.